# DocumentApp.openById(fileId) fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I try to open a file just created in my drive like this :

```
    var listing = DriveApp.createFile("listing.txt", "Drive file listing");
    ...
    var fileId = new String(listing.getId());
    ...
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(fileId);
```

I get the following message : Argument non valide. (ligne 21, fichier "Code") / Invalid argument...

"appsscript.json" contains :

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"
  ]
```

What is missing ? File exists, content is "Drive file listing"..., file creation date is defined...

Sincerely

Comment: Try putting saveAndClose() between the creation and opening.

Answer (score 1):

Your main error is about concepts. You're creating a ***.txt format file***, therefore Drive will not be able to open it and modify. You would have to create the document in a format supported by Drive and then using [`DocumentApp.openById(fileId)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openById(String)).

I recommend you using better the [`createFile(blob)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob).

Answer (score 0):

I choose to create a string using new String because I was getting the same behaviour with only getId()

var listing = DriveApp.createFile("listing.txt", "Drive file listing");
 var doc = DocumentApp.openById(listing.getId());